# Conver array of sting to array or JSON based on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

In my project I am stuck in this task.I have array of string like this:

```
var tempArray = [];
tempArray[0]="key1 : value1";
tempArray[1]="key1 : value2";
tempArray[3]="key2 : value1";
tempArray[4]="key2 : value2";
tempArray[5]="key2 : value3";
```

Now I want result something like this:

```
   "key1":"value1","value2"
   "key2":"value1","value2","value3"
```

You can use JSON or array I just want result in this formate.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I have tried with array but not getting the logic :(

Comment: `I have array of string like this` Why in the first place are you starting with an array of this kind???

Comment: @A.Wolff - just had to ping you, the accepted answer to this one is just fantastic, it's worth it.

Comment: @adeneo Wow, i dicn't think it was possible... ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff - ain't that something, it even uses jQuery, that does all things.

Comment: @adeneo It is still missing some jQuerish, e.g: `var tempA = $([]).get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function... I don't know if there is a specific function for this but I make a function which will do what you want...

```js
function getMultArray(temp) {

  var newArray = {};
  var key;
  var oldValue = null;
  var tempA = [];
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  $.each(temp, function(k, value) {
    var newValue = value.split(" : ");
    j++;
    if (oldValue === newValue[0]) {
      tempA.push(newValue[1]);
      if (temp.length == j) {
        newArray[oldValue] = tempA;
        tempA = [];
      }
    } else {

      if (i === 0) {
        i = 1;
        oldValue = newValue[0];
        tempA.push(newValue[1]);
        if (temp.length == 1) {

          newArray[oldValue] = tempA;
          tempA = [];
        }
      } else {
        newArray[oldValue] = tempA;
        tempA = [];
        tempA.push(newValue[1]);
        oldValue = newValue[0];
        if (temp.length == j) {

          newArray[oldValue] = tempA;
          tempA = [];
        }
      }

    }
  });
  return newArray;
}


var tempArray = [];
tempArray[0] = "key1 : value1";
tempArray[1] = "key1 : value2";
tempArray[2] = "key2 : value1";
tempArray[3] = "key2 : value2";
tempArray[4] = "key2 : value3";
var newArray = getMultArray(tempArray);
$.each(newArray, function(key, value) {
  $.each(value, function(i, value) {
    $("#result").html($("#result").html()+"<br/>"+key + "-" + value);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks result is exact what i want :)

Comment: sorry to all as its not perfect answer, I am not that much knowledgeable as you people sorry.@CodeStar please accept any other answer which do your task.

Comment: @AnandSingh Be aware, nothing rude here, but just quite funny [inside joke](http://motyar.blogspot.fr/2013/01/1-not-enough-jquery.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to transform your array however you like:

```
var output = tempArray.reduce(function(result, item) {
    var key = item.split(":")[0].trim();
    var value = item.split(":")[1].trim();
    if (result[key]) {
        result[key].push(value);
    } else {
        result[key] = [value];
    }
    return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` here to good effect.

```
var out = tempArray.reduce(function (p, c) {
  var arr = c.split(' : '), key = arr[0], value = arr[1];
  p[key] = p[key] || [];
  p[key].push(value);
  return p;
}, {});
```

Note that this gives you an object the value of which are arrays. You can access them like this:

```
out.key1[0] // value1
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/82esves7/)

Comment: This question is tagged with jQuery, so please use it!... ;)

Comment: Having seen that accepted answer I don't think my skills are up to it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
(function() {
  var tempArray = [];
  tempArray[0] = "key1 : value1";
  tempArray[1] = "key1 : value2";
  tempArray[3] = "key2 : value1";
  tempArray[4] = "key2 : value2";
  tempArray[5] = "key2 : value3";

  function parse() {
    var _tempArr = {}

    tempArray.forEach(function(item) {
      var k = item.replace(/\s+/, "").split(":");
      if (_tempArr[k[0]] !== undefined) {
        _tempArr[k[0]].push(k[1]);
      } else {
        _tempArr[k[0]] = [];
        _tempArr[k[0]].push(k[1]);
      }
    });

    console.log(_tempArr);
  }

  parse();

})()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change the data formato to a more concise style with just only the `key` like `'key1'` and the `value` like `'value1'` and not a combined string like `"key1 : value1"`.

The result is an object with the keys as properties and the values as elements in an array.

```js
var object = {};

function addValueWithKey(key, value) {
    object[key] = object[key] || [];
    object[key].push(value);
}

addValueWithKey('key1', 'value1');
addValueWithKey('key1', 'value2');
addValueWithKey('key2', 'value1');
addValueWithKey('key2', 'value2');
addValueWithKey('key2', 'value3');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```